# zip all content in a folder exclude big files

Tags: file, zip, size

I have a folder containing a lot of files and multiple layers of sub-directories. I would like to zip the folder including the entire content, but exclude all files that is bigger than a certain value, lets say 1000 Mb.

Anyone has any idea about how to accomplish this task?

Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Linux, Mac OS X, or Cygwin, Use `find` to list the files and pipe the file names to `zip`

```
find Folder -type f -not -size +1000M | zip foo --names-stdin
```

This will list recursively all files in Folder whose size is not 1000 Mb or greater and archive using zip into a file named foo.zip.

Comment: This was very helpful! Just the thing I needed. While testing I learned that "1.5M" does not work, and that 1500K doesn't either — it's "1500k". Learn something new every day!